# Purpose of Nonclustered indexes in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

(New to SQL Server)
I am struggling to understand purpose of Nonclustered indexes in SQL Server. Read though MS documentation (both for v2012 and v2008 that has pretty pictures) and some online resources, but still have a lot of unanswered questions.

1. Does noncl. index maintains sorted B-tree ? As far as I understood, it does - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933130%28v=sql.80%29.aspx, otherwise analogy of book index would not make any sense.
2. Why on earth you want noncl. index to be defined on table or view with a clustered index or on a heap ? Heap has no order, so defining noncl. index on heap makes some sense - you can quickly find exact matches. However, table with clustered index is already organized data, and defining noncl. index will only speed up exact searches.

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2014-01/unreasonable-defaults-primary-key-clustering-key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got two questions in here:

**1. Does the nonclustered index have a sorted B-tree?** Yes, because you have to get to the right page of the index to find the data you're looking for.

**2. Why do you want a nonclustered index when you also have a clustered index?** Think of the white pages of the phone book as your clustered index. If you wanted to find all of the people in your city with a first name of "Brent", then the clustered index isn't going to do you much good - the clustered index is based on last name, first name, middle initial. Wouldn't it be helpful to have a separate phone book sorted by first name?

Just like in real life, the answer to that might be yes or no - but it depends on how often you search for people by first name, and how often people move in/out of your city, or how often people change names.

Comment: Brent, thank you for answer. I have been enjoying Brent & Co. videos on Youtube. MS docs, your videos, along with several blogs are the best source of information I found so far.

It seems like, tables that don't get updated too often, and queried for exact value and for ranges of values might a good candidates to have both types of indexes. Now it all makes sense !

Comment: Cool, glad I could help.